# How to Sort table rows in Rails ? (the best way)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am going through railscast http://railscasts.com/episodes/228-sortable-table-columns but since it is 3 year old video I was wondering, is this still the best way to sort in rails ? I found https://github.com/thoughtbot/sortable_table but this is not maintained anymore.

Comment: here is another gem - https://github.com/dadooda/handles_sortable_columns

Comment: Thanks, will surely check it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend going with a much more up to date solution [datatables](http://www.datatables.net/) which will do exactly what you want and more! You can sort, search and select multiple tables. A full documentation is available detailing different options.